# How can I write a good template for this. I get this error: "member reference base type 'void' is not a structure or union"

Tags: c++, qt, templates, methods, referenceerror

This is my code for the template I try to create. I'm thankfull for some suggestions and tips. Is this right or could you create it better?
And actually I get this message: "member reference base type 'void' is not a structure or union"

```
template <class T>
void example(QVector<T> &vec, const QString &fp, std::function<void(QFile&)> func)
{                                                /* Is this right? I don´t have to say "T" anywhere? 
Because here I would pass a method from a class(void myClass::method(QFile&) )*/

    QFile f(fp);
    if(!f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append) )
    {
        qDebug() << "File error" << f.error();
    }
    else
    {
        QThread::currentThread();
        for(T &tw : vec)
        {
            //tw.func(f);
            func(f).tw;  // member reference base type 'void' is not a structure or union                     
        }
    }
    f.close();
}
```

func could be this:

```
//...class definition...
//declaration of the method:
void writeTeams(QFile&);

//definition (this pass to func)
void teamType::writeTeams(QFile &f)
{
    QTextStream out(&f);
    out.setCodec("UTF-16LE");
    out << teamId << "\t" << offsideTrap << "\t" << withoutBall << "\t" << formationId << "\t"
            << attack << "\t" << teamMentality << "\t" << attackTactic1 << "\t"
            << attackTactic2 << "\t" << defenseTactic1 << "\t" << defenseTactic2 << "\t" << captain << "\t"
            << penaltyTakerId << "\t" << kickTakerId << "\t" << leftCornerkickTakerId << "\t" << rightCornerkickTakerId << "\t"
            << numTransfersIn << endl;
}
```

I would use the template in following code:

```
...
filePath = "teamwrite.csv";
    QFuture<void> f = run(example, teams, filePath, &teamType::writeTeams); //teams came from this: QVector<teamType> teams;
...
```

Is this right?

Comment: Did you forget to `#include <functional>` before using `std::function`?

Comment: No, it is in. But I forgot to write it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a *pointer to member function* (pmr) where you need a *pointer to function* (the converting constructor of `std::function`).

You need to either declare `writeTeams` as `static`, or else *bind* the pmr to an instance of `teamType` (the invisible first argument of a pmr), to give a `std::function` that takes a single argument.

Let's simplify your code to a minimal, complete example (since the Qt and template stuff is just a distraction here):

```
#include <functional>

void example(std::function<void(int)> func)
{
    func(1);
}

struct teamType
{
    void writeTeams(int);
};


int main()
{
    example(&teamType::writeTeams);
}
```

This won't compile:

```
60725415.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
60725415.cpp:19:13: error: could not convert ‘&teamType::writeTeams’ from ‘void (teamType::*)(int)’ to ‘std::function<void(int)>’
   19 |     example(&teamType::writeTeams);
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |             |
      |             void (teamType::*)(int)
```

---

I can either write (if `writeTeams` doesn't need any `teamType` members):

```
struct teamType
{
    static void writeTeams(int);
};
```

Or I can bind to a specific instance of `teamType`:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    teamType the_team;
    example(std::bind(&teamType::writeTeams, the_team, _1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this won't work. We have to consider, I would pass a member! function to a function. And this member function is used in the template by this way:

```
for(T &tw : vec)
{
    tw.func(f); // I think this is correct
  //func(f).tw;     // not this                  
}
```

That means(I'm not sure) in `std::function<void(int)> func` we have to advise there is always a class involved in this template anyway .